# My blender textures are only visible when in texture paint, but disappear when in any other mode

Tags: texturing, uv

I made a cylinder and UV unwrapped it with with an image in the UV editor. I start painting textures and they show up, only to disappear after I go to a mode other that texture paint :/
Also, I forgot to mention, I'm sort of new to blender and don't know how to use nodes and some other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new material and apply the texture you painted to it and then you can go to material preview or rendered view to see if it looks good.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out I set it to texture image rather than material mode!